# how to find a certain char in string and replacing it with the spaces, left in that string with anonymous function in haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

I need to write a function ,with the use of **foldl**, which recieves a string "str"
and returns an anonymous function. The anonymous functions receives a char 'c' and exchanges every instance of 'c' in "str" with the remaining number of chars in the string "str"

```
                          speak :: String -> (Char -> String)
```

example:

"Hello" 'e' -> "H3llo"

"gate" 't'  -> "ga1e"

I've tried this code, but cant get it to work properly:

```
speak :: String -> (Char ->String)
speak str = foldl (\x -> if x == str then x = show(length str) else str) str
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign a value to `x` What you need to do is either return `show (length xs) ++ xs` in case the character `x` is the same as the one you are looking for, or `x:xs` (so a normal prepend of `x` to `xs`) in case it does not match. Your `speak` also has a `Char` as first parameter, and then converts a `String` to a `String`, so:

```
speak :: Char -> String -> String
speak c = foldr (\x xs -> if c == x then show (length xs) ++ xs else (x:xs))
```

or with swapped parameters:

```
speak :: String -> Char -> String
speak str c = foldr (\x xs -> if c == x then show (length xs) ++ xs else (x:xs)) str
```

Comment: The OP required `foldl`, but `foldr` is much more natural here. Also note that the above code might (?) produce the wrong output if the length is >= 10 and we have multiple instances of `c` to replace. E.g. in `speak 'x' "xbxbbbbbbbbbbb"` the first `x` is not replaced with `length "bxbbbbbbbbbbb"` but with `length "b11bbbbbbbbbbb"` -- it is not clear to me which length is the intended one for this task.

Comment: The intended outcome from xbxbbbbbbbbbbb should be 13b11bbbbbbbbbbb